# ProxyPass SSL over two local Apache instances

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, proxy

I have a Debian server running 2 Apache server instances locally

The reason is one is running PHP 5.2 and the other is PHP 5.3

I have a macro to proxy off to the 5.3 server on certain directories. I specify the directories in a virtual host declaration

This is the macro

```
<Macro NewPHP>
        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
</Macro>

<Macro NewPHPIn $directory>
        ProxyPass $directory http://127.0.0.2/$directory
</Macro>
```

And I use it like so

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName foo.co.nz
        DocumentRoot /var/www/foo.co.nz

        <Directory /var/www/foo.co.nz>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        Use NewPHP
        Use NewPHPIn /bar/
</VirtualHost>
```

This makes `http://foo.co.nz` run on PHP 5.2

And `http://foo.co.nz/bar` run on PHP 5.3

Now the problem is I need to do that same for SSL but I cant figure out how to get it working. Ive tried lots of different things and cant find any help elsewhere.

Does any one have any idea that may help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a trick similar to this to get it working.

http://blog.revolunet.com/index.php/reseau/administration/hosting-multiple-ssl-vhosts-on-a-single-ipportcertificate-with-apache2